# How to prove the given set is convex

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

I was given to prove the solution set of the following constraints is a convex set.

$x_1+2x_2+x_3 \leq 10$ , $x_1 - 2x_3 \leq 9$ , $x_1 \geq 2$ , $x_2 \geq 0$ , $x_3 \geq 0$

**My Attempt:**  That can be written as $AX \leq B$  where $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 &  -2 \end{bmatrix}$  and $B = \begin{bmatrix} 10 \\ 9 \end{bmatrix}$

Let's suppose $Y  , Z$  are two solutions of $AX \leq B$ . It can be easily proved that  $c_1 Y + c_2 Z$  will also be solution of $AX \leq B$  and $c_1 Y + c_2 Z$ will satisfy other constraints.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the result that half-spaces are convex (which is not too difficult to prove), and the fact that the intersection of convex sets is also convex. Since each constraint of your solution set is a half-space (in $\mathbb{R}^3$), it follows that the solution set is convex.